# Smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sigma^n=\epsilon$ for every $\sigma\in S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\sigma^n=\epsilon$ for every $\sigma\in S_5$

I'm doing some practice problems from a textbook and came across this question. It's not included in the answered questions in the apendix, so I'm a bit unsure about how to efficiently do this. In previous examples the order of $S_n$ was small enough that I could compute $n$ by hand.

I also came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356734/permutation-for-finding-the-smallest-positive-integer) that is asking a very similar question, but in that case they have their product of disjoint cycles given to them. Not entirely sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

The order of $\sigma \in S_n$ is the lcm of the orders of the cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition, which corresponds to a partition of $n$.

Bottom line: consider all partitions of $5$ and the lcms of their terms.